# HTML: Image won't display?

Tags: html, image, web

I'm kind of new to HTML. I'm trying to display an image on my website but for some reason, it just shows a blue box with a question mark in it. I've looked everywhere on the internet, but none of the solutions seemed to work for me. I've tried:

```
<img src="iwojimaflag.jpg"/>

<img src="images/iwojimaflag.jpg"/>

<img src="Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Acme/WebBundle/Resources/public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Where is your image stored relative to your HTML file (ex: HTML is at "myapp/index.html" and image is at "myapp/images/myimage.jpg" ?

Comment: image: "/Resources/public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg" --------------------
html: "/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig"

Answer (score 14):

Just to expand **niko**'s answer:

You can reference any image via its URL. No matter where it is, as long as it's accesible you can use it as the `src`. Example:

**Relative location**:

```
<img src="images/image.png">
```

The image is sought **relative to the document's location**. If your document is at `http://example.com/site/document.html`, then your `images` folder should be on the same directory where your `document.html` file is.

**Absolute location**:

```
<img src="/site/images/image.png">
<img src="http://example.com/site/images/image.png">
```

or

```
<img src="http://another-example.com/images/image.png">
```

In this case, your image will be sought **from the document site's root**, so, if your `document.html` is at `http://example.com/site/document.html`, the root would be at `http://example.com/` (or it's respective directory on the server's filesystem, commonly `www/`). The first two examples are the same, since both point to the same host, Think of the first `/` as an alias for your server's root. In the second case, the image is located in another host, so you'd have to specify the complete URL of the image.

**Regarding `/`, `.` and `..`**:

The `/` symbol will always return the root of a filesystem or site.

The single point `./` points to the same directory where you are.

And the double point `../` will point to the upper directory, or the one that contains the actual working directory.

So you can build relative routes using them.

Examples given the route `http://example.com/dir/one/two/three/` and your *calling* document being inside `three/`:

```
"./pictures/image.png"
```

or just

```
"pictures/image.png"
```

Will try to find a directory named `pictures` inside `http://example.com/dir/one/two/three/`.

```
"../pictures/image.png"
```

Will try to find a directory named `pictures` inside `http://example.com/dir/one/two/`.

```
"/pictures/image.png"
```

Will try to find a directory named `pictures` directly at `/` or `example.com` (which are the same), on the same level as `directory`.

Comment: Ok so I tried going to "http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/Acme/WebBundle/Resources/public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg" and I got a 404 not found error, but I double checked that the picture is there!! I also double checked that the url is right!

Comment: I also tried `<img src="..."/>' and replaced the `...` with what you said above but according to my directory. Didnt work.

Comment: If you're specifying the host's name you should precede it by http:// or whatever protocol you use to retrieve the image. Also note that the root of your site =/= the root of your filesystem. Http://localhost may point to /var/www/ not /.

Comment: You see, when you start a server, it'll set a *virtual root* on the filesystem, and it'll be located at the folder it's configured to be the **website's root**. Let's say your filesystem's root is `/`, and your server is configured to set it's root to `/var/www/`, so `http://localhost/` will start at `/var/www/`, and if you try to access `http://localhost/pic/image.png` you have to have your image at `/var/www/pic/image.png`

Comment: Likewise, if your document is at `http://localhost/doc/index.html` or `/var/www/doc/index.html` on the filesystem and if your document calls for an image with `src=pic/image.png` your image should be at `/var/www/doc/pic/image.png`. Or if src=/pic/image.png then it'll have to be at `/var/www/pic/image.png`

Comment: @Gretta are you sure that your `src` attribute reads `images/image.jpg`?

Comment: Yup. `<img src="images/iwojimaflag.jpg"/>` I literally copied and pasted that. Though I checked the file type and it says it's a jpeg image. But the extension is jpg..?

Comment: The extension doesn't matter, have you tried removing that trailing `/`? have you tried with another image (on another host, like http://goo.gl/AJm0rS ?)

Comment: Yes, I've tried using another image. I don't know what you mean by the trailing `/` because I don't see it. The image only shows up if I just type in the website address that I got it from.

Comment: Instead of `<img src="…"/>` use `<img src="…">`, what do you mean by *just type in the website address that I got it from*? where do you type the address?

Answer (score 4):

Lets look at ways to reference the image.

Back a directory

```
../
```

Folder in a directory:

```
 foldername/
```

File in a directory

```
 imagename.jpg
```

Now, lets combine them with the addresses you specified.

```
 /Resources/views/Default/index.html
 /Resources/public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg
```

The first common directory referenced from the html file is three back:

```
 ../../../
```

It is in within two folders in that:

```
 ../../../public/images/
```

And you've reached the image:

```
 ../../../public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg
```

Note: This is assuming you are accessing a page at domain.com/Resources/views/Default/index.html as you specified in your comment.

Comment: so... what am I supposed to write in my code? `<img src="/public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg/>"`? Because that didn't work for me. I also tried `<img src="../../../public/images/iwojimaflag.jpg"/>` and that also didn't work.

Comment: Well..... what is the address in your address bar when you are viewing index.html?

Comment: You already wrote it up there. `../Resources/views/Default/index.html`

Comment: So... you already have the answer then. Just look above. If it doesn't work, look in your browser debugger and address errors... or fix your website setup. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/gmmneK/children_593313_340.jpg"/>

<img src="https://image.ibb.co/e0RLzK/entrepreneur_1340649_340.jpg"/>

<img src="https://image.ibb.co/cks4Rz/typing_849806_340.jpg"/>
```

please see the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you put   `<img src="iwojimaflag.jpg"/>` in html code then place iwojimaflag.jpg and html file in same folder.

If you put `<img src="images/iwojimaflag.jpg"/>` then you must create "images" folder and put image iwojimaflag.jpg in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Very old case but...

There is still another reason for which the browser may not find your image. In fact is a sub-case of the previous "Incorrect file paths" issue.

Check if the HTML header includes a `<base href="">`. If that is the case, no matter where your HTML file is, all the paths will be anchored in the root folder defined in the `<base>` instead. So you may have your image file in the same folder that the HTML file and not being able to load it.

Answer (score -1):

I confess to not having read the whole thread. However when I faced a similar issue I found that checking carefully the case of the file name and correcting that in the HTML reference fixed a similar issue.
So local preview on Windows worked but when I published to my server (hosted Linux) I had to make sure "mugshot.jpg" was changed to "mugshot.JPG". Part of the problem is the defaults in Windows hiding full file names behind file type indications.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the most common reasons:

- Incorrect file paths
- File names are misspelled
- Wrong file extension
- Files are missing
- The read permission has not been set for the image(s)

**Note:**
On *nix  systems, consider using the following command to add read permission for an image:

```
chmod o+r imagedirectoryAddress/imageName.extension
```

or this command to add read permission for all images:

```
chmod o+r imagedirectoryAddress/*.extension
```

If you need more information, refer to this [post](https://www.thoughtco.com/images-not-loading-4072206).

Answer (score -3):

I found that skipping the quotation marks "" around the file and location name displayed the image...
I am doing this on MacBook....