# Background-Image not shown in browser

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

So I tried to add a background image in the header and It's working fine when I open the HTML file from the editor as a live server, but when I open the file normally from the browser (without the live server in the VScode) the image not shown up.

```
.header{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("/img/hero.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

also, this error is shown to me(Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) but the image is already in the same direction

Comment: try this instead `background-image: url("./img/hero.jpg");`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24254708/19068

Comment: that does not work because it give wrong directory

Answer (score 1):

The Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND means that a file can't be found. This can occur because there's the file doesn't exist, it's in a different directory than the one we specified, or its in the correct place but the name doesn't match the name specified. You can open image in the browser and get the url from it.

Comment: Thank you it's worked but I think when I need to send the source code it's better to add the image name than its URL so the problem still

Answer (score 0):

adding .. in the file path should resolve it. I had the same problem.  so it should be

```
  background-image: url("../img/hero.jpg");
```

Comment: It's better to provide path info, you've assumed css lies on one path and images other.

Comment: I wonder if this question (and answer) is specific to some kind of default file structure when you create a project in vscode?